# Javascript: Select elements by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an HTML list

```
<ul>
  <li id="item-foo"></li>
  <li id="item-bar"></li>
  <li id="zoop"></li>
</ul>
```

and in Javascript I want to get an array of the list items **based on their ID**. Basically, if the ID starts with `item-` then I want to get it in an array.

The first way I did this was just to loop through all the items in the DOM and take the ID as a string and match it that way. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the other answers, jQuery selectors like `[id^='item-']` will work fine, but it should be noted that this is *not* a jQuery-only feature, but rather a DOM selector, as specified by [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).
In other words, if you don't feel like including a monolithic toolkit like jQuery, just so you can use some *more special* selectors, just write:

```
var itemIds = document.querySelectorAll("li[id^='item-']");
```

And you're there.
What's more, this will be faster than jQ. jQ can never match vanillaJS for speed. There's no need for you to use jQ here, so don't. JQ can make life easier, true, but not in this case. The selector is identical, so you don't need jQ.
All jQ will do here is slow you down, and help you write bad code... Sorry... I needed to get that off of my chest.

Comment: This does not work in older IE versions, jQuery is more compatible.

Comment: @FlashThunder: `querySelectorAll` was supported back in the IE8 days. The X-browser argument doesn't stack up anymore. jQ 2 has X-browser issues with IE8 (believe me, I know: select elements on change event delegation doesn't work, for example). Queryselectorall is better supported than `getElementsByClassName`. [Check](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) before voting down!

Comment: I did not vote down, don't worry :) jQuery 1.x - IE7+ compatible jQuery 2.x - not IE compatible.

Comment: @FlashThunder: Well than, I'd like to know who did... anyway: jQuery's selectors use the [sizzle selector toolkit](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js), which is packed with `querySelectorAll` calls

Comment: I checked it out. jQuery 1.9 can select in IE8 and `querySelectorAll` not. Anyway why would I vote down your answer? It is good to know that something like `querySelectorAll` exists.

Comment: @FlashThunder: I'm sorry for blaming the DV on you. It's just that I expect DV's to be explained in a comment, and you were the only one to comment. Of course, it wouldn't make sense, acknowledging an answer is correct, and still DV, but I've been getting some random DV's lately, and no explanation... it's a tad annoying, that's why I responded a tad bitchy. Sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

The proper selector in jQuery would be:

`$('li[id^="item-"]')`

Comment: The same selector can be used in VanillaJS, which will always be faster than using jQ.

Comment: Indeed, in jQuery or any browser with `querySelectorAll` (which is all modern browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Use selector: `var some_array = $("li[id^='item-']")` from here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: It's not a *jQuery* selector. It's just a selector.

Answer (score 0):

`$("[id^='item-'"]`

If you want to use jQuery, that selector should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Come on, jQuery is not the digital second coming... this is a standard selector, which doesn't require jQ at all. `document.querySelectorAll` is implemented in more browsers than `getElementsByClassName` is... the chances of X-browser issues are close to zero, _don't use jQ if you don't need it!_

Comment: The author included jQuery in the tags of their question so I assumed that it was already being used elsewhere. I also quantified my answer with "If you want to use jQuery". I also don't need to be told _don't use jQ if you don't need it_; everyone knows that at this point.

Comment: Granted, my comment may not have conveyed what I actually wanted to say: the part where you said _"If you want to use jQuery, that selector..."_. My point is simply that _that selector_ does not require jQ to give the OP what he's actually after.